# Can you import a library from one repo into a web app in another repo using Webpack?

Tags: javascript, git, npm, webpack, vue.js

So I have a library with Vue.js components, and I have a Vue web app, that imports those components. Both run on Webpack and both are in separate repositories.

Before using webpack, I used browserify-hmr and could use npm link to import the library from my dev env into the web pack. Essentially, it did the same as `import '../../../library/index.js'`

With Webpack, I get an error like this:

```
ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 errors
1:16:18 PM

This dependency was not found:

* !!vue-style-loader!css-loader!../../../web-app/node_modules/vue-loader/lib/style-rewriter
?id=data-v-6afebbcb!sass-loader!../../../web-app/node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector
?type=styles&index=0!./Component.vue in ../TheLibrary/src/Component.vue

To install it, you can run: npm install --save !!vue-style-loader!css-loader
!../../../web-app/node_modules/vue-loader/lib/style-rewriter?id=data-v-6afebbcb
!sass-loader!../../../web-app/node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector?type=styles
&index=0!./Component.vue
```

I'm trying to make changes to the library locally, and import it in my web app locally, too, without having to push up the library changes and pull the module updates from the web app. Is there anyway to do with with Webpack?

Also, the webpack project was built using this https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack

**Update**

The error is happening because the library has a dependency, https://www.npmjs.com/package/susy, which is not installed on the web app. As soon as I install that dependency on the web app, the error goes away.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way in your case is to move your common functionality to npm package and use it into dependencies of both webpack projects. This is the right way!

Comment: Actually, the library is the common functionality. It's suppose to be used in two separate web apps.

Also, check out the update for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found a solution to this. It's all in webpack's resolver. Things work in webpack v1, maybe because it has this line in the `build/webpack.base.js`

```
resolve: {
  fallback: [path.join(__dirname, '../node_modules')],
  ...
```

But webpack v2 doesn't seem to work the same way. My work workaround looks like this...

```
resolve: {
  modules: [
    path.join(__dirname, '../node_modules/TheLibrary'),
    ...
```

Now it looks inside the symbolically linked library for its dependencies.

**Note**: If TheLibrary also has a symbolically linked library, then under this workaround you need to include that as well under the root web app. Something like this...

```
resolve: {
  modules: [
    path.join(__dirname, '../node_modules/TheLibrary'),
    path.join(__dirname, '../node_modules/TheLibrary/node_modules/Component'),
    ...
```

So still open to better solutions :)